# java.io.IOException:setdatasource failed status = 0xFFF

Tags: java, ioexception, mediametadataretriever

I am trying to get duration of .amr file by using MediaMetadataRetriever.Bur Every time I use, It give me the Error. Following Is the code to calculate the Duration. But it gives Error at SETDATASOURCE.newfile is the file i have created at runtime.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(newfile.toString());
            int duration =  
Integer.parseInt(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));


            int durSec = duration;
            durSec = durSec/1000;
            int durHour = durSec/3600;
            durSec = durSec%3600;
            int durMin = durSec/60;
            durSec = durSec%60;
            String Time = durHour+":"+durMin+":"+durSec;
            tv_duration.setText(""+Time);
            mmr.release();
```

Comment: What type of Object is "newfile"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want "newFile.toString()" try using [java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()). I'm not sure what "newFile" is so I'm grasping at this one.  .toString() will use the method on the object which may not necessarily provide a concise path.

Comment: What's this "Java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()". I can't get it.

Comment: Couple of clarifications: assuming you are on Android for this, and is the newFile object a File object?

Comment: Yes,I am working in Android. newFile is File object.

Comment: Then replace newFile.toString() with newFile.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: It gives same error.java.io.IOException:setdatasource failed status = 0xFFF

Comment: Please provide more context in your question on how 'newFile' is created.

Comment: final File newfile = new File(path+"/"+tv_no.getText().toString());   Here is code for new File.

Comment: Ok hopefully not stating the obvious, are you certain the for exists, has more than a zero length, and is not open in another thread?